# Share wvdial internet connection through ethernet

Tags: linux, networking, router, internet-connection

I have a PC which is connected to internet using a USB dongle and wvdial.

I would like to share the internet connection over Ethernet with other PCs using a router.

How can I connect the PC, and share its connection via Ethernet? I have connected the router to it with an Ethernet cable and I can access to it from other PCs, but I can't use it as gateway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be solved with `iptables`

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i ppp0 -o wlp2s0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlp2s0 -o ppp0 -j ACCEPT
```

`wlp2s0` is the destination connection (can be `eth0` or any other)
`ppp0` is the connection from the dongle.